# JdbcTemplate as json output from weblayer

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdbc

am using JDBCTemplate (in spring maven) to get data here i can only get first_name value by using id = 1 "http://localhost:8080/data/userData/1" is there any way to get all data as json output??

```
public Object userCall(int id) throws Exception {
        try {
            return JdbcTemplate.query("select id,first_name,last_name,email,dob from users WHERE id=" + id + "", new IdMapper());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
     public Object extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {


                Object toReturn=null;
                while (resultSet.next()) {

                toReturn = resultSet.getObject("first_name");
                resultSet.getObject("last_name");
                resultSet.getObject("email");
                resultSet.getObject("dob");


            }


            return toReturn;

        }
```

Comment: use : select id,first_name,last_name,email,dob from users

Comment: i have problem with' resultSet' need multiple value using id

Comment: You are only making the first name so why would you expect something else. Create a user object, assign all the fields and return the User object. Also NEVER use a String concat to create a query it isn't safe nor performant. Use ` ?` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `List<Object>` `resultList` like this:

```
     public List<Object> extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

      List<Object> resultList = null;
        while (resultSet.next()) {
             resultList = new ArrayList<Object>();

            resultList.add(resultSet.getObject("first_name"));
            resultList.add(resultSet.getObject("last_name"));
            resultList.add(resultSet.getObject("email"));
            resultList.add(resultSet.getObject("dob"));
           }
            return resultList;
```